# Why does the ssh package not work in release verison?

Tags: android, flutter

I am using flutter ssh package..

When I am testing my app in debug mode, the app works fine and ssh package works fine, but when I build a release version of the app, ssh doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
var client = SSHClient(host: "234.34.65.3", port: 22, username: "aesr", passwordOrKey: "aesraesr");
 Future getData()async{
    await client.connect();
    await client.execute("iwconfig").then(
        (value){
          setState(() {
            data = value;
          });
        }
    );
  }
```

UPDATE:
this my AndroidMainfest File

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: What does your release `AndroidManifest.xml` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem when running app in release or using a release apk. I solved it by adding these 2 lines in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        // ADDED THIS LINES
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And adding a proguard-rules file in `android/app`:

[image: Screenshot]

And adding this inside:

```
# Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class com.jcraft.**  { *; }
```